# SDN4 - Neo4j 3.0.6 - neo4j-ogm 2.0.5 : Cannot fetch when findByPropertyParentId

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have two classes that have M-N Relationship and one of that class have Parent Class. The problem is, I want to return list of object when I call leftRightRepository.findByLeftParentId(id) but it always return an empty List.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Right{

    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id; //random generated UUID

    String name;

    //Properties & Constructor
}


@NodeEntity
public class Left{

    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id; //random generated UUID

    String name;

    ParentClass parent;

    //Properties & Constructor
}

@NodeEntity
public class ParentClass{

    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id; //random generated UUID

    String name;

    //Properties & Constructor
}


@NodeEntity
public class LeftRight {
    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id;

    @Relationship(type = "LEFTRIGHT_LEFT", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Left left;

    @Relationship(type = "LEFTRIGHT_RIGHT", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Right right;

    //Properties & Constructor
}
```

To make it easier, I attach the picture of my Nodes
[image]

When I check with findAll(), and then look at the property, it have correct parent Id. Is it Bug? In SDN3, Its work, but in SDN4, I cannot use it again.

And I try a little workaround code, with findByLeftId(List ID). In SDN3 it work too, but in SDN4 it not work again.

Comment: SDN 4.1.x or 4.2.x?

Comment: spring-data-neo4j-4.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code should work. Possible to supply test data or your project for us to look at?

Comment: Okay, I will provide the sample project today.

Comment: @Luanne here is the sample Project. https://github.com/daviduck123/spring-data-neo4j-4

Comment: Thanks, will take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDN 4 / Neo4j OGM only supports one level of nesting at this point in time. The finder you are trying to execute is two levels of nesting: `LeftRight`->`left`->`parent`

The only alternative now is a custom @Query.

Perhaps you can also log a feature request [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH)

Comment: Okay, I already create the issue, Thank you for your time and explanation.